# как результат выполнения функции определить в качестве переменной либо записать в текстовый файл?

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как результат выполнения функции def main() определить в качестве переменной либо записать в таблицу, текстовый файл и т.д.?

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        group_id = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        group_id = lst # ввод id групп
        for i, ids in enumerate(group_id):
            members = get_all_members_3(group_id) #ввод айди группы
            for member in members:
                #вывод по городу
                keys = {'title'} #переменная для вывода города
                for citys in member: #цикл для вывода группы
                    for attribute in keys:
                        try:
                            print(member['city']['title'])
                        except KeyError:
                            pass
```

интересует именно результат вывода
`print(member['city']['title'])`
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вернуть из функции

```py
......
for attribute in keys:
    try:
        return(member['city']['title'])
    except .....
```

записать в файл

```py
.....
for attribute in keys:
    try:
        with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as file:
           file.write(member['city']['title'])
    except .....
```

Comment: Он все равно не сохраняет результат

Comment: @Демид интересное утверждение. Если вы опишите в вопросе, что конкретно вы хотите, то возможно вам дадут ответ на это. Сейчас, из разряда черной магии, я должен гадать

Comment: я разобрался, сам неправильно вписал в исходник предоставленное Вами решение, большое спасибо!!!